# SignalR: how Server can establish connection to Client?

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr

Is it possible to implement this kind of logic:

Server establishes connection to Client.
Then the Client uses this connection to send requests/responses to the Server?

That is a c# pair: client and server apps.

SignalR? Websockets?

Comment: What are you calling a Client and a Server?  Depending on the Network Layer it can have a different definition.  You can have a Client PC use a Server application, and have a Server PC be a Client Application.  So one is the PC Network Layer and the other is the Application Layer.

Comment: You are right, it can be described as: App1 connects (via http) to App2, then App2 sends requests to App1 using this connection.

Answer (score 4):

In SignalR, a client app can connect to a SignalR Hub on a Server. Once connected, the client app can call methods defined in the SignalR Hub on the server, and the server can use SignalR to call methods on the client. The client app in this example can be JavaScript running in a web page, or a .NET client.

Note that there's no way for the server to initiate a connection from a SignalR Hub to a client. The client app will always have to initiate the connection.

Comment: for your latter point is there a link in the documenation that says that regarding the client needing to establish the connection?

Comment: That's just how SignalR was built. Most clients are behind a firewall anyway with network address translation done at the router. As a thought experiment, how would a server reach out to a particular browser behind a firewall with NAT? But with the client initiating the connection, firewalls and NAT are not an issue.